# Chefdk 0.10.0 not passing ssh-key when bootstrapping

Tags: chef-infra, chefdk

Im using chefkdk 0.10.0 and trying to bootstrap some rhel nodes with my ssh-key..which ive copied to all of the servers and verified i can ssh without it asking for a password. However, when i use chefdk to bootstrap the node it still asks me for the passowrd. I also tried using the -i flag to specify my identity file and still no luck. Could it be a bug with chef?

```
[jn*****@toolbox ASPChef]$ chef exec knife bootstrap corp********.********.com -x root --node-name corp********.********.com
Doing old-style registration with the validation key at /home/jn*****/Public/Chef/cookbooks/ASPChef/.chef/csm-validator.pem...
Delete your validation key in order to use your user credentials instead

Connecting to corp********.********.com
root@corp********.********.com's password:
```

Comment: Can you show us the SSH command you're using? Are you sure you're also SSHing as the same user as Chef is?

Comment: Is your public key (probably /home/jn****/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) really in /root/.ssh/allowed_keys on the target machines ? If not use -x jn*** and the sudo options of knife bootstrap.